# mobile number validation best way to support voip, extension or mobile number ( domestic +international numbers)

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

Tried the below code for achieving mobile number validation  to support voip, extension or mobile number ( domestic +international numbers).

```
func validate(value: String) -> Bool {
    let PHONE_REGEX = "[0123456789][0-9]{9}"
    let phoneTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", PHONE_REGEX)
    let result =  phoneTest.evaluate(with: value)
    return result
}
```

But it is not working for numbers like (+21) 54683920 .

Please help.

Comment: On a white eye, the regex isn't fit for this sample, you should use PhoneNumberKit, this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit).

Example of usage from repo:

```
do {
    let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse("+33 6 89 017383")
}
catch {
    print("Generic parser error")
}
```